# Can I see a video replay of my run?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I have just run 8616 metres in Jetpack Joyride, however I didn't record the run as I did not know I was going to get that score. Is there any way to instant replay my run so I can record and save it to my PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Jetpack Joyride does not have a replay or theater mode. Your screenshot will have to suffice as proof of your achievement.